# When yielding pytest.File or pytest.Item instances, how can I indicate that these need fixtures?

Tags: pytest

Given the following mock up:

```
import pytest


class DummyFile(pytest.File):

    def collect(self):
        yield DummyItem(self, self)


class DummyItem(pytest.Item):
    def __init__(self, pytest_file, parent):
        super(DummyItem, self).__init__(pytest_file.name, parent)
        self.pytest_file = pytest_file

    def runtest(self):
        ...

def pytest_collect_file(self, parent, path):
    if path.ext == ".rst":
        return DummyFile(path, parent)
```

How can I indicate that `DummyFile` or `DummyItem` instances need a particular fixture?

How can I then get hold of those fixtures, both from the `DummyItem` and its parent `DummyFile`, inside `DummyItem.runtest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of August 2017, there's no official API for accessing fixtures from `pytest.Item` subclasses, see this [Github issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2471).  The poster of that issue has a [Github gist](https://github.com/cjw296/sybil/blob/552d3ff2d6e8639ee5d3c8efa26f5e535e064ae8/sybil/integration/pytest.py#L41) showing the internal APIs you have to use:

```
fm = self.session._fixturemanager
names_closure, arg2fixturedefs = fm.getfixtureclosure(names, self)
fixtureinfo = FuncFixtureInfo(names, names_closure, arg2fixturedefs)
self._fixtureinfo = fixtureinfo
self.funcargs = {}
self._request = fixtures.FixtureRequest(self)
```

Comment: Yep, the poster of that issue was me ;-)

Comment: Ah, I couldn't tell :).  Anyway, I hope having your issue linked here will help the next person who stumbles across this question.